# ms query man min date month query

Tags: ms-access, date, max, monthcalendar

I am trying to develop an access based database for a small company. I have made few tables, some of them are the "2011/2012 Total Production in $" and ""2011/2012 Total Production in CY."
All four tables have a column "Actual Production"

Now, using query tool, i have to achieve two objectives.

1. get the maximum and minimum production of each month in a year
2. display the date of when the Actual Production was maximum/minimum in the month

I have accomplished first task which was simple; Make a query, get relevant fields, Summary Max & Min and finally distrubute in month wise. I.e Jan Max 5000, Min 2000...Feb Max 6000 Min 1000

Now what i desire is to display the date of max or min production for the month. So if April had MAX 181,218.00 in its month, I want it to display the date when it occurred (i,e April 10th 2012)

I am a beginner with Access, so please be as simple as possible.

Sample data gleaned from comment:

```
Month         Sum of Prod   Min Prod in $ Max Prod in $
------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
January 2011  $1,184,096.98    $20,486.40   $171,470.40
February 2011 $1,558,072.20    $44,962.20   $116,359.20
March 2011    $1,744,442.19    $19,200.00   $141,065.10
April 2011    $1,698,608.63    $27,500.70   $181,218.00
May 2011      $1,826,915.38    $37,996.00   $130,066.00
June 2011     $2,317,890.71    $42,645.00   $144,323.30
```

The above data were few of the fields gnerated by Query.

What I am looking for is

```
Month         Date of Min Prod Min Prod in $ Date of Max Prod  Max Prod in $
------------- ------------- ------------- -------------     -------------
January 2011     Jan 15        $20,486.40     Jan 10         $171,470.40
February 2011    Feb 20        $44,962.20     Feb 27         $116,359.20
March 2011      March 10       $19,200.00     March 1        $141,065.10
```

and so forth.

Is it possible to use a query to generate this result?

thanks!

Relation to the comment.

Relevant fields in one of the tables are.

```
Date of Activity Actual Production  
-------------   ------------- -------
1/3/2012              $20,486.40    
1/4/2012              $44,962.20    
1/5/2012              $19,200.00
```

Comment: urgghhh...cant even make proper columns here to show my issue

Comment: I just edited the question Thankyou Hans.

The query is generated from two tables, one giving production in $ amount and the other in Cubic Yard. 

The tables have some calculated fields and two fields where user input is required (Date and Actual Production).

(table posted in the question for clarity)

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i needed.

sorry for the confusion. And I can't thank you enough!

YOU ROCK!!! :D

Comment: I didn't realize you saw that answer before I deleted it.  I did that because I realized it could give multiple rows for a month if the Actual Production value in more than one row of the daily data matched the monthly minimum; same for the monthly maximum.  However since it was actually useful to you, I'll undelete that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lost in the details of your question.  So I'll show you sample data and queries to get something like what I hope you want from that data.

Here is the contents of `tblAbbas`.

```
activity_date actual_production
1/3/2012             $20,486.40
1/4/2012             $44,962.20
1/5/2012             $19,200.00
2/1/2012                  $3.00
2/2/2012                  $2.00
2/3/2012                  $1.00
```

Here is the SQL for a query named `qryMonthStart`.  The purpose of this query is to determine the first day of the month which includes the `activity_date`.

```
SELECT
    DateSerial(Year(activity_date),Month(activity_date),1)
        AS month_start,
    activity_date,
    actual_production
FROM tblAbbas;
```

The query below uses `qryMonthStart` as its data source and gives me this result set.

```
month_year    SumOf_production min_prod_date MinOf_production max_prod_date MaxOf_production
January 2012        $84,648.60      1/5/2012       $19,200.00      1/4/2012       $44,962.20
February 2012            $6.00      2/3/2012            $1.00      2/1/2012            $3.00
```

And the query SQL ...

```
SELECT
    Format(grpby.month_start,"mmmm yyyy") AS month_year,
    grpby.SumOf_production,
    qmin.activity_date AS min_prod_date,
    grpby.MinOf_production,
    qmax.activity_date AS max_prod_date,
    grpby.MaxOf_production
FROM
    (
    (
        SELECT
            month_start,
            Sum(actual_production) AS SumOf_production,
            Min(actual_production) AS MinOf_production,
            Max(actual_production) AS MaxOf_production
        FROM qryMonthStart
        GROUP BY month_start
    ) AS grpby
    INNER JOIN qryMonthStart AS qmin
    ON
            (grpby.MinOf_production = qmin.actual_production)
        AND (grpby.month_start = qmin.month_start)
    )
    INNER JOIN qryMonthStart AS qmax
    ON
            (grpby.MaxOf_production = qmax.actual_production)
        AND (grpby.month_start = qmax.month_start)
ORDER BY grpby.month_start;
```

Beware that query will fail ("data type mismatch in criteria expression") if you have Null for `activity_date`.  The simplest way to prevent that is to clean out the Nulls then prohibit them in the `activity_date` column (set the Required property to Yes in table design view).  If you decide you must allow Nulls in `activity_date`, you've got more work ahead.

Also note that query will give you multiple rows for the same `month_year` if the `actual_production` values in more than one of the daily records for that month matches the monthly minimum (`MinOf_production`).  And the same situation will apply for the monthly maximum (`MaxOf_production`).